# Use batch to find strings in a csv file

Tags: batch-file

I have a txt file with a number in every line, and a CSV file with multiple columns.

I'm trying to find coincidences using batch, what I need is to check the 3rd column of every row, and get the row to another csv if the number in that 3rd column is one of the numbers in the txt file.

Example:
**file.txt**:

> 12
>   13
>   14
>   15

**file2.csv**

> hello,world,10
>   hello,world,45
>   hello,world,14
>   hello,world,23

**output.csv**

> hello,world,14

I'm not used to batch and I'm having trouble with this one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Could you edit this post so it is easier to understand what it is you're trying to achieve out of this program? As well as what you have tried, and the errors you encountered? It is very hard to help when the question is not clear.

Comment: Based exactly upon the information you've provided, a single line should be all that's required: `@FindStr /EG:"file.txt" "file2.csv">"output.csv"`. If youre actual examples are not a proper representation of the issue you're having, this would obviously be less liekly to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

That's a simple command:

```
findstr /eg:file.txt file2.csv >output.csv
```

Note: a line like `hello,world,2014` would show up ("false positive") because it ends with `14`

If the last column always has two digits, that's not a problem. If not, `file.txt` has to be adapted to include a leading comma, like:

```
,12
,13
,14
,15
```

Answer (score 0):

**Powershell** script used to *filter* contents based on the keys present in the other file.

```
$keys = get-content "keyfile.txt"
$content = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Header Word1,Word2,Word3 -Path "file2.csv" 
$content | Where-Object { $keys -contains $_.Word3 }  | Export-Csv -Path "result.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

if requires you can save the output in file & used for further process.